# How to make Gmail open as a separate windowed Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to create a "Chrome app" to open Gmail in a separate windows Chrome instance on my Mac.

The method for doing this is well documented - https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en-GB

In Chrome, you go to the three dots for Settings > More Tools > Create Shortcut and then tick "Open as new window" when you name the shortcut.

However, when I click on the resulting Gmail icon, it opens in Gmail back in the main Chrome browser window, not a separate app window.

Answer (score 1):

I checked mine and noticed the same behavior so I just went and recreated the shortcut for a new instance. Tried it and it works in its own window/app. Deleted the old one.

Try again?

Comment: I came here looking for a way to get tabs in these new windows though. Doesn't seem to be a way to do that.